# What are the Deviants doing on Earth?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals

In *[Eternals (2021)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternals_(film))*, the Eternals' arrival on Earth is in 5000 BC in Mesopotamia, when humans were already well established.

It is only then that the Deviants seem to be a danger (triggering the Eternal's arrival), so **where were the Deviants before**?

Generally speaking, the Eternals were created as a countermeasure to the Deviants, who somehow must "get" to the planet they put in danger (arrive, exist since the beginning of the planet, etc.). Since they are a missed experiment, they are not "exported" to new planets on purpose.

Are there Deviants on each planet that have life? (If all planets were created at the same time, that could be plausible.) But then why have they waited so long on Earth? And why would they appear on new planets (created by new Celestials)?

---

<sup>*Note: Sorry for the repetitions of "Eternals" and "Deviants", but I wanted to avoid using "them/they," which I find ambiguous in such a question.*</sup>

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviant_(comics)#In_other_media which is linked in the Wiki page you linked to in your question.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: I saw that in Wikipedia but the chronology is not clear to me. Has that team of Eternals waited until the Deviants (that were in that case on Earth since its beginning) evolve enough to be a danger (why not kill them before). Or is it that **all** Deviants started with **all** inhabited planets and started to be a danger "just now" (5000 BC our time) ?

Answer (score 5):

The Deviants were sent by Arishem to certain Celestial host planets prior to 5000 B.C.. They are seen killing dinosaurs, which will support their intended purpose of clearing out predators so that intelligent life will arise.

> ARISHEM: I created the Deviants, Sersi, for the same purpose I created you. Every Celestial host planet has its own predators. I first sent the Deviants to exterminate them so intelligent life can grow, but there was a flaw in the design. They evolved, became predators themselves. And I lost control of them.

They had begun to be a menace to intelligent life by 5000 B.C. (Babylon) and so the Eternals were sent to eliminate them. A tipping point was reached where Deviants were consuming humans in such amounts that the coming of Tiamut was being significantly retarded.

> ARISHEM: In order to grow, Tiamut needs vast amounts of energy from intelligent life. The Deviants prevented this by consuming humans until the Eternals eliminated them.

It seems most likely that Earth was one of the planets that seeded with Deviants by Arishem. It may be that with the arising of sophisticated Babylon in 5000 B.C., humanity passed the developmental threshold at which their intelligence could contribute to the coming of Tiamut. At that point Arishem could no longer tolerate the ravaging raids of the Deviants on humanity and the Celestials were sent to eradicate the Deviants.

However I note that the Marvel Cinematic Universe wikia entry [hedges its bets here](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Deviants#Creation_and_Rebellion), stating that Deviants 'spread across the galaxy'.

> Having lost control of the Deviants, who were now running rampant across the galaxy, Arishem created a new race to combat them, synthetic rather than organic, and named them Eternals. It became the role of the Eternals to exterminate the Deviants and protect seeded worlds, and Eternals soon hunted Deviants across the galaxy. Multiple Deviants came to the planet Earth seeded with the Celestial Tiamut, prior to 5000 B.C, and became feared by the local human population.

So from the point of view of the (usually reliable) MCU wikia, Deviants 'arrived' from some third party planet, which suggests that Deviants are capable of space travel and were not placed on Earth by Arishem.

However this seems unnecessarily speculative to me. **From in-movie dialogue alone, I am satisfied that the Deviants were placed on Earth by Arishem.**

Comment: How could they have been **placed** on Earth by Arishem, when your first quote states, "I first **sent** the Deviants..."

Comment: @JohnnyBones I mean that the Deviants were on Earth specifically by the will of Arishem rather than by independently 'spreading across the galaxy'. Here I use the word 'sent' more like 'sent in the mail' than 'sent by command to a sentient creature'.

Comment: @JohnnyBones A celestial's will might as well be the word of god.

Answer (score 0):

> Where were the Deviants before?

#### The Deviants have been on Earth since prehistory, before the Eternals were created and long before the Eternals came to Earth in 5000 BCE.

This is confirmed by the book, *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)*, which gives the official history of the MCU events:

[image: Chronology of events regarding the Deviants and the Eternals in "The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline"]

Arishem created the Deviants to help the growth of intelligent life on the planets that had Celestial seeds. The Deviants were supposed to eliminate the wild predators that threatened the intelligent life forms. However, the Deviants had a flaw in their design: they could evolve and adapt, and they became predators themselves. That’s when Arishem sent the Eternals to stop them and prepare host planets for the emergence of the new Celestials.

> Are there Deviants on each planet that have life?

There are Deviants on every planet that has a Celestial seed. They are part of Arishem’s plan to create more Celestials.

> But then why have they waited so long on Earth?

The Deviants did not wait on Earth. They were active throughout prehistory and history, but they were mostly hunted by the Eternals. They only resurfaced in the present day because of the awakening of the Celestial seed.

Answer (score -1):

The movie and the source material differ widely on the Deviants.

**Source Material**

In the source material, Celestials select the dominant race of a given planet and alter their genetic structure for reasons that have not yet been revealed. The Celestials use their advanced technology to alter the race into three distinct races:

a) The mainline race that shows normal attributes until evolution and an outside catalyst creates mutation, granting individuals of the mainline race a wide array of varying abilities.

b) A superior race dubbed Eternals who are typically empowered with cosmic energy, and

c) a genetically unstable race dubbed Deviants. The Celestials have practiced these tests on various races such as Humans, Kree and Skrulls.

When the First Host **got to the planet Earth, the Celestial Gammenon the Gatherer collected a few specimens, which Ziran the Tester mutated to create one hundred grotesque Deviants** (Homo descendus). After Ziran was done with its brood, Nezarr the Calculator performed his own tests and created 100 superior Eternals (Homo immortalis). Finally, Oneg the Prober created a latent gene for the expansion of human potential.

After these creations were released back on Earth, the Eternals secluded themselves, while the Deviants established an empire on the continent of Lemuria.  The Deviants multiplied quickly, while the Eternals mostly hid for a while, tried to fight the Deviants and eventually called the Celestials for help.

**MCU**

In the MCU, The Deviants were a race of genetically engineered organic beings, created by the Celestial Arishem the Judge in order to assist in the process of Celestial seeding. Arishem created the Deviant race with an intended role; to wipe out the apex predators of seeded worlds and thus allow sentient life to evolve. For a time, the Deviants succeeded in this role, killing of the predators of many worlds.  The problem was, the Deviants eventually became the apex predators and began killing all the humans, and as a result the Celestial wasn't getting fed.  **It is never specified where they were created, or how they arrived at their destination worlds**.  It is known, however, that they arrived sometime before the Eternals and the Celestials had realized they were killing the native Human population at an accelerated rate.

In 5000 BC, ten superpowered Eternals—Ajak, Sersi, Ikaris, Kingo, Sprite, Phastos, Makkari, Druig, Gilgamesh, and Thena—are sent by the Celestial Arishem to Earth on their starship, the Domo, to exterminate the invasive Deviants.  In 1521, the last of the Deviants on Earth were hunted down and killed by the Eternals. However, in Alaska, a group of them that included the leader, Kro, had become frozen in ice, and remained so for centuries.

In 2023, due to the Blip, the ice defrosted, and Kro and his pack were set free.  The Eternals learned that they were never supposed to kill off the Deviants, but rather prepare Earth for the emergence of a Celestial.

As you can see, the movie and the source comics are pretty far apart on what The Eternals were even supposed to be doing on Earth.  They also differ widely in that in the source material, the Deviants were created on Earth by Ziran the Tester, whereas the movie never specifies where the Deviants were created, just that they were created by Arishem the Judge and later sent to Earth.

Comment: There are two issues w/ this answer. 1. Your claim that the movie and source material differ wildly is not explained in the second paragraph. The origins appear to be the same (or at least, not exclusive/conflicting) between both. 2. "*However, another wave of Deviants were sent to Earth in the present day.*" Sent to? By whom? For what purpose? What's the source for this claim? Deviants reduce the population on Celestial-seeded planets, preventing the Celestials from being born. That is why Eternals are sent to kill Deviants on certain planets.

Comment: You are incorrect about the movie. No new deviants were sent - some survived in a glacier that then thawed out. The Eternals were supposed to kill them, otherwise there wouldn't be enough humans to feed the Celestial.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect changes that were suggested.  @TylerH - The movie vs source differ in so much as in one, the Deviants were dominant on Earth from the time they were created, while in the other the Deviants were near extinction at one point.

Comment: this still doesn't provide information on **how the Deviants got on Earth originally**...

Comment: Edited again with more info than is probably necessary.  There shouldn't be any holes in the explanation now.

Comment: But it doesn't say **how**!!!

Comment: @taylor.2317 thats the part where you wave your hand and say "somehow they made it to earth." You may recognize this technique from the bad writing brought to you by the rise of Skywalker "somehow palpatine has returned",

Comment: @taylor.2317 - I bolded the part that states it is never specified how they got to Earth.  That's not my fault, it's poor writing on whoever wrote the screenplay's part.  *shrugs*  The source material says they were created here, the movie kinda botched that up.